# Create shortcut for python mainfile in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In many projects I switching the active file in VSC Editor all the time, but if I want to run the program startscript I type `python mainfile.py` in the terminal. I wanted to rise my overall performance and implemented a shortcut for the command `-python.execInTerminal`. This works as intended but involves the step of switching manually to the `mainfile.py`. Is there a possibility to add the functionality to remove this step in the process?

I am looking for following, when I press my shortcut:

1. execute a file which is marked as master/root/whatever file (like in Texstudio). or...
2. switch to the file and then execute it (prefer variant 1).

Comment: You can set `"program": "mainfile.py",` in your .vscode/launch.json. And then use F5 to run that file.

Comment: My F5 shortcut is with python connected to debug and it seems to be the default. Can I run different launch files?

Comment: Maybe running without debug (Ctrl+F5) would be useful for you?

Comment: I tested it but it seem to make no defference betwen debugging and without debuging. It always launches the debugger.